Spring Webflux: uploading more than one empty file will only process the last empty file
I have a use case in my application where the user might need to upload more than 1 empty file. The endpoint looks like this:
public Mono<ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO>> upload(@RequestPart("files") Flux<FilePart> fileParts) {
    // fileParts.flatMap(filePart -> // will only contain the last empty file always if more than one empty file is uploaded)
}

The problem that I'm having is that when uploading more than 1 empty file, the Flux fileParts will only contain the last empty file. I'm running on the last version of spring which at the moment is 3.3.5. How to bypass this?
